# Local development with planetscale DB and Laravel, Laravel Valet

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet, planetscale

Maybe I'm doing something wrong but when developing locally (Laravel Valet, Laravel) it feels unresponsive/slow it always takes about 2 seconds till the first bite transfer.

[image]

My internet connection is not an issue here 100%. I settled everything according to the documentation everything is working but this bottleneck is not acceptable when developing locally, the database is empty just a couple of demo tables. Is this expected behavior maybe?